MariaDB loads for whm/cpanel server are very high. What would be recommended values?
I checked the etc/my.cnf file and these are the values.
performance-schema=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=77000
innodb_file_per_table=1
plugin-load-add=auth_socket.so
unix_socket=OFF

The server is a 64GB RAM and 16 core processor.
MariaDB Version: 10.11.9
What would be the right configurations to tackle the high MariaDB loads.
I wanted to change these values and I'm not sure of the right numbers to use.

a) socket isn't a boolean, unclear why you want it off. b) Can you include a show global status or a link to after raising innodb_buffer_pool size to ~32G if you have that much spare. flush global status and waiting a few hours at least.

What is "MSQL" in your question? The DBMS of Hughes Technologies? If so then why you then tell about MariaDB? And what do you mean when use the term "high MSQL loads"?

innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728

That is an old default.  Change to 45G to take better advantage of your large RAM -- and probably speed things up.
